Unix: Why symlinked shell interpreter still has an effect of the original interpreter?
In my Unix system, /bin/sh is symlinked to /bin/bash.

/bin/sh -> bash*

As this is the case, I expect that if an executable has a shebang of:

#!/bin/sh

it will be equivalent to:

#!/bin/bash

However, this is not true.
For example, below code uses process substitution which is supported by bash only:
#!/bin/bash
echo ${BASH_VERSION}
diff <(echo -e "1\n2") <(echo -e "2\n2")

Result:
4.2.46(2)-release
1c1
< 1
---
> 2

If I change the shebang to /bin/sh, as follows:
#!/bin/sh
echo ${BASH_VERSION}
diff <(echo -e "1\n2") <(echo -e "2\n2")

Result is:
4.2.46(2)-release
test.sh: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `('
test.sh: line 3: `diff <(echo -e "1\n2") <(echo -e "2\n2")'

Moreover, even if remove the shebang, and run the script explicitly:
/bin/sh test.sh

I get the same error.
Weirdly (or maybe not), running the following will work:
`realpath /bin/sh` test.sh

I'm looking for an explanation for this behavior - as this is unexpected in my understanding, since /bin/sh -> bash. Also, the value of BASH_VERSION is consistent.
Thank you.

argv[0] lets the program tell which name was used to start it. bash deliberately runs in compatibility mode (equivalent to set -o posix) when started under the sh name. (This is also how one busybox executable can provide every standard UNIX utility, with all of ls, cp, etc linked to it; or how grep, egrep, fgrep, &c can all be provided by one executable)

BTW, don't use echo -e -- even the POSIX spec for echo specifies that if you want to use backslash-escape sequences, you should use printf instead; the [unix.se] question Why is printf better than echo? has an excellent answer that goes into more detail. (Even when your shell is 100% certain to be bash, echo -e will sometimes strictly comply with the POSIX spec and print -e in output, when the right combination of flags is set).

From the documentation:

When invoked as sh, Bash enters POSIX mode after reading the startup files.

This includes disabling bashisms like process substitution.

Thanks for the documentation. However, I still don't understand how come double-square brackets are supported in this mode? As this is also a bash feature and not a sh one.

It apparently doesn't disable everything.
